# Dynamic RecyclerView content with Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a simple activity where I have to show a dynamic list of reservations. The list has to be synchronized with the Firebase Realtime DB.

### What I did

I created a `Reservation` class with the relative `ReservationAdapter` and the dedicated layout `item_customer_reservation.xml`. Up to now, I populate every item with the same informations, just for testing purposes.

```kotlin
class ReservationAdapter(private val reservationList: Array<Reservation>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ReservationAdapter.ReservationViewHolder>()
{
    inner class ReservationViewHolder(private val binding: ItemCustomerReservationBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    {
        fun bind(reservation: Reservation)
        {
            Log.w(Constants.CUTITAPP, "ReservationViewHolder:onBind")
            binding.apply {
                // TODO dummy informations
                tvSalonName.text = "test salon"
                tvServiceName.text = "test name"
                tvServiceDate.text = "test date"
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ReservationViewHolder
    {
        val binding = ItemCustomerReservationBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ReservationViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(reservationViewHolder: ReservationViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        reservationViewHolder.bind(reservationList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = reservationList.size
}
```

This is the Fragment that hosts the RecyclerView:

```kotlin
class CustomerHomeFragment : Fragment()
{
    private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference

    private var uid: String? = null

    private var reservationList: Array<Reservation>? = null
    private var reservationAdapter: ReservationAdapter? = null

    // view binding
    private var _binding: FragmentCustomerHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            uid = it.getString(Constants.UID)  // get the UID from the passed parameter
        }

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        reservationList = arrayOf()
        reservationAdapter = ReservationAdapter(reservationList!!)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View
    {
        // inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentCustomerHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        addCustomerReservationsEventListener()

        binding.apply {
            rvReservations.adapter = reservationAdapter
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView()
    {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null  // needed to destroy the binding when the fragment is destroyed
    }

    /**
     * Adds a [ValueEventListener] for the reservations of the customer.
     * Populates the reservationList with the [Reservation] of the customer and notifies the adapter.
     */
    private fun addCustomerReservationsEventListener()
    {
        val reservationsReference = db.child(Constants.DB_CUSTOMERS).child(uid!!).child(Constants.DB_CUSTOMER_RESERVATIONS)
        val customerReservationsListener = object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(reservationUidListSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                // get reservationUidList
                val reservationUidList = reservationUidListSnapshot.getValue<HashMap<String, String>>()
                Log.d(Constants.CUTITAPP, "reservationUidList: $reservationUidList")

                if (!reservationUidList.isNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    // get a Reservation for each Uid to populate the list
                    for (reservationUid in reservationUidList.values)
                    {
                        if (reservationUid.isNotEmpty()) // TODO temporary fix
                        {
                            db.child(Constants.DB_RESERVATIONS).child(reservationUid).get().addOnSuccessListener { reservationSnapshot: DataSnapshot ->

                                val reservation = reservationSnapshot.getValue<Reservation>()
                                reservationList = reservationList?.plus(reservation!!)
                                reservationAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                
                                Log.d(Constants.CUTITAPP, "reservationList size: ${reservationList?.size}")
                                Log.d(Constants.CUTITAPP, "reservationAdapter size: ${reservationAdapter?.itemCount}")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError)
            {
                Log.w(getString(R.string.app_name), "CustomerHomeFragment:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        reservationsReference.addValueEventListener(customerReservationsListener)
    }

    companion object
    {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(uid: String) =
            CustomerHomeFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(Constants.UID, uid)  // pass the parameters to the created Fragment
                }
            }
    }
}
```

### Problem

The `reservationList` collects the Reservation of the user (currently in the DB I added one reservation for testing), its size is 1; it correctly contains a `Reservation` object with the correct data that i have in the DB.
The problem is that the `reservationAdapter` has 0 items inside, like the `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not working. The result is that the RecyclerView is empty.

How can I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Does this object `val reservation = reservationSnapshot.getValue<Reservation>()` contain the correct data?

Comment: Yes, it is a `Reservation` object with all the correct data inside.

Comment: `D/CutitApp: class: com.mrizzo.cutitapp.models.Reservation, uid: test-reservation, date: Mon Jul 25 13:22:39 GMT+02:00 2022`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get a **solution**.

`reservationList = reservationList?.plus(reservation!!)` creates a new Array object, that is not linked to the Adapter (the old empty array is still attached to it).

The solution is to use `ArrayList` instead of `Array` in the `ReservationAdapter`, then change the `onDataChange()` like this:

```kotlin
override fun onDataChange(reservationUidMapSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
{
    reservationList?.clear()
    reservationAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

    // Get reservationUidMap
    val reservationUidMap = reservationUidMapSnapshot.getValue<HashMap<String, String>>()

    if (!reservationUidMap.isNullOrEmpty())
    {
        // Get a Reservation for each UID to populate the list
        for (reservationUid in reservationUidMap.values)
        {
            db.child(Constants.DB_RESERVATIONS).child(reservationUid).get().addOnSuccessListener { reservationSnapshot: DataSnapshot ->

                val reservation = reservationSnapshot.getValue<Reservation>()
                reservationList?.add(reservation!!)
                // Notify the adapter of the changes
                reservationAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.
Cheers!